# Possible to Store a HashMap in the ServletContext?

Tags: java, casting, hashmap, servlets

Is it possible to store a HashMap into the ServletContext in Java?  When I go to get the attribute back it's a String...is there a way to cast it back to a HashMap?  Its technically a

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<byte[]>>
```

I Set the Attribute like this:

`event.getServletContext().setAttribute("Banners", getAllBanners());`

The method getAllBanners() returns a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<byte[]>>` object. Then when I want to access it I call:

`event.getServletContext().getInitParameter("GBPBanners");`

EDIT**

Got it `HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<byte[]>> myMap = (HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<byte[]>>) event.getServletContext().getAttribute("Banners");`

Comment: Can you post the code you use?  It's possible you're pulling back the wrong thing.  And what is the string value?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you can serialize the HashMap object and retrieve it when you need!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me:

```
ServletContext ctx = request.getServletContext();
ctx.setAttribute("map", Collections.singletonMap(7, "Seven"));

//And later...

Map<Integer, String> map = (Map<Integer, String>) ctx.getAttribute("map");
String value = map.get(7);    //"Seven"
```